# Mixing generic methods and extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

I created the `Class1.GetChild<T>() where T : DependencyObject` extension method in *lib1.dll* assembly. After that, all assemblies that depends on *lib1.dll* failed to compile with error:

> The type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' is defined in an assemebly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'WindowsBase' etc...

Why dependent assemblies requires *WindowsBase* even if they don't use `GetChild`?

.

To reproduce (vs2010 .net4):

**lib1.dll** (references *WindowsBase*)

```
namespace lib1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static T GetChild<T>(this DependencyObject src) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public static class Class2
    {
        public static int SomeExtMethod(this string src)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**lib2.dll** (references *lib1* but not *WindowsBase*)

```
using lib1;
class someClass
{
    void someFct()
    {
        "foo".SomeExtMethod(); // error: The type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'
                // is defined in an assemebly that is not referenced. 
                // You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase' etc..
    }
}
```

.

***Update:***

I think there's definitly something when mixing generic methods and extension methods. I tried to demonstrate the issue in the following sample:

```
// lib0.dll
namespace lib0
{
    public class Class0 { }
}

// lib1.dll
using lib0;
namespace lib1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static void methodA<T>() where T : Class0 { }    // A
        public static void methodB(Class0 e) { }                // B
        public static void methodC(this int src) { }            // C
    }

    public static class Class2
    {
        public static void methodD(this String s) { }
    }
}

// lib2.dll
using lib1;
class someClass
{
    void someFct()
    {
        Class2.methodD("");  // always compile successfully
        "".methodD();        // raise the 'must add reference to lib0' error depending on config. see details below.
    }
}
```

`A, //B, //C` -> compile ok

`A, B, //C` -> compile ok

`//A, B, C` -> compile ok

`A, //B, C` -> raise error

`A, B, C` -> raise error

`//A` means `methodA` is commented. As Damien pointed out, type inference might play some role. Still curious to know the ins and outs.

Comment: I think that, due to the possibility of Type Forwarding, it can't decide whether the extension method is applicable for *any* object *until* it's seen the definition of the type in Windows Base.

Comment: I didn't get it. Let's change the method to : *public static T GetChild<T>(this DependencyObject src) where T : class*. Now *lib2.dll* compiles ok but it still can't see the definition of the type. What's changed?

Comment: Is it trying to rebuild `lib1.dll` when you do a build?  Are you including the reference to that library as a Project reference or a reference to the dll itself?

Comment: @Bobson - When rebuilding `lib2.dll`. Both Project reference or dll reference produce the same error.

Comment: @Thomas - Yeah, I realized that once I did my own testing for my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your situation has been answered by Microsoft here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/668498/problem-with-extension-method-in-c-compiler

There are other use-cases as well independent of extension methods which produce this error wrongly.

Consider this:

1. Define a generic method in a type, say TP1, defined in library say LB1.
2. Type constrain the generic method on some type defined in some other library LB2.
3. Define another method in TP1.
4. Now in your library reference only LB1 and try to call the second method of type TP1

If you don't use TP1 but some other type defined in LB1, you do not get the error.
Also, even if one of the method of type TP1 expects a parameter of the type defined in LB2 (and you do not call this method) it does not produce this error

Answer (score 2):

When one assembly depends on another assembly, the first assembly also depends on *all* the dependencies of the other--regardless of what is used.  Assembly dependencies are effectively decoupled, another version of either assembly can be deployed after compilation, the compiler can't know that under circumstances like this one or more of the dependencies in the second assembly won't be used by the first assembly.

To solve the issue you can simply add a reference to WindowsBase.

Or, as prashanth points out, put the `SomeExtMethod` into a different assembly so code that uses that doesn't need to take a dependency on WindowsBase.

Update:
If you don't use anything from an assembly, you don't need any of its dependencies.  But, as soon as you use one assembly, you need all the dependencies of that assembly as well.  This is apparent in the way Visual Studio add references.  If you add a reference to an assembly, it will copy all the dependent assemblies (not registered in the GAC) into your debug/release directories along with the assembly you added.

Update:
As to the compile error: that's the way it was written--there may be no other reason.  Is it a good idea to get a compile error if you don't reference dependent assemblies?  Maybe, you're likely to use something from a reference and that might use something directly from the references references--better a compile error than a deployment error.

Why not a compile error on *every* non-referenced secondary dependency?  Again, it was written that way.  Maybe an error here too would be good; but that would be a breaking change and would require really persuasive reasons.

Comment: Better, decouple the string extension methods into another library.

Comment: This answer's not entirely correct - I have a project at work which has 34 references, and it is itself referenced by (and in fact provides the core functionality to) a project with 10 references.

Comment: @bobson I'm not clear how a project with 34 references that is referenced by a project with 10 references means it's not dependant on all the references' dependencies. Eg you can't load an assembly if that assembly's references are not available, ergo the first assembly is dependant on all the references of its references.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - not true. An assembly's references are only loaded when something that relies on those references is actually used. If there's a standalone class ("C1") in that assembly that references nothing else, then all of the referenced assemblies can be missing but the assembly can still be loaded, and "C1" used.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Just tried it: created a class library (lib1) and added a class, created another library that used the first library (lib2).  Then created a console application to use a class in lib2 (a class that doesn't use anything in lib 1)  Adding a reference to lib2 copied lib1 as well.  If I delete Lib1, the console application will not load and a FileNotFoundException is thrown.  Sure, if I don't use anything from lib2, neither lib2 nor lib1 needs to load; but as soon as lib2 is required, so is lib1.

Comment: @bobson I just tried it again, VS copies the dependent assemblies (but does not add references to them) and if I delete those other copied files and try to run, I get FileNotFoundException.  So, I see nothing in my answer the is not entire correct.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - The issue that Thomas is having has nothing to do with copied dlls.  He can't **build** the project.  He's not getting a FileNotFoundExcpetion at runtime, he's getting a "must add a reference" warning at buildtime.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - To address your first response: The issue is that *I don't need to manually reference those 34 references in the smaller project*.  All the dlls are copied over, but I don't get a "You must reference this" error at build time.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - in re: your "Just tried it: created a class library (lib1) and added a class, created another library that used the first library (lib2)" comment. I did exactly that here. Deleted lib1, ran the console application, created an instance of a class from lib2. No error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Don't know what to tell you, failed for me.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - Re: "Why not a compile error on every non-referenced secondary dependency?" Because if it's not in the function signature, then lib2 doesn't need to know about it.  The dll will be silently copied over at link time, but the code will build just fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be answered by anyone other than someone on the compiler team. I'm now thinking that it's to do with type inference - but whereas *§7.6.5.1 Method Invocations* talks about inference, *§7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations* is silent on the matter - despite the fact that inference obviously does take place when searching for applicable extension methods.

I think it's attempting some form of inference *before* it's performing the comparison on identifiers (which would immediately rule out the extension method since it's got the wrong name). Obviously, it can't perform any form of inference for this type if it's unable to understand the type constraints.

Hence, when you change your type constraint to just `class`, it now successfully passes over this method - it can infer a type parameter, but it now eliminates this extension method successfully.

Comment: The fact that referencing one assembly that references another wasn't a give away?

Comment: @PeterRitchie - you can consume an assembly without adding any of *its* references, provided you avoid using any members of that first assembly that expose referenced types (as parameter values, base classes, etc). The rules for extension methods imply that the second consideration for applicability would be the identifier, but the compiler appears to be attempting type inference first. If it left type inference until later, this extension method would not be applicable, and so we would have no exposure to `DependencyObject`.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - and my point is that, when you're not using types from an assembly (either directly, or via types exposed by an intermediate assembly), you *do* *not* *need* to reference that assembly. Compilation (which is what this question is talking about) can proceed without requiring that reference.

Comment: correction: My point is you still have a dependency on that other assembly, even if you don't need to reference it (although, sometimes you do need to reference it as well). You <s>can</s>can't run without all the dependencies of the assemblies you use.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - and that's what we're disagreeing about in comments under your own answer. You definitely *can* run without all dependencies present.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - see e.g. this [blog post](http://www.thegatesofdawn.ca/wordpress/posts/2009/07/17/delay-loading-assemblies-in-net/) where someone was searching for a `/delayload` option - before discovering that it's the default for .NET.

Comment: Delay load?  And when a type from that reference is used, you get the exception.  No different than what I said...

Comment: @PeterRitchie - we're obviously missing each others points here. When `lib2` is delay loaded, I can use classes from within it. Only when I use a class that exposes a type from `lib1` will `lib1` be delay loaded. If `lib1` is not present, I can still use `lib2`, provided I avoid functions/classes that rely on `lib1`.

Comment: Damien, you are making the assumption that you are running under the .NET Framework JIT. NGEN (now automatic in Windows 8) and store compilation (ie Phone 8) will break that assumption.

Comment: I agree with Damien on the "delay-loaded/missing-assemblies" debate (no idea on how ngen and WP8 works). Concerning the "must add a reference" error, I awarded this answer because I think it gives the closest match so far. See my update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference another assembly, I assume the compiler needs to be able to parse **any method signatures** defined in that assembly, so it knows where to go to find that function if it sees a call to it.

If you replace your `GetChild()` function with

```
    public static T GetChild<T>(this T src)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(DependencyObject)) return default(T);
        else return default(T);
    }
```

or something similar to that, it does **not** require you to include the reference to *WindowsBase* that you're running into.  But if you add `where T : DependencyObject` to the signature, it **does** require it.

Effectively, you can use whatever assembly references you want in a project, so long as you don't expose them in any way.  Once you expose them, then every other project which uses your library needs to be able to handle them, and thus requires those references themselves.

Comment: Try this:  create a class library (lib1) and add a class (or use the pre-created one), create another library (libs) that uses the first library (edit pre-created class to use class from lib1), and add another class that uses nothing from lib1 (Class2).  Then create a console application and add a reference to lib2.  You'll notice lib1 was also copied to your debug directory.  Use the class (Class2) from lib2 that doesn't use lib1.  Build, delete lib1 and try to run the application.  FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - To elaborate on my comment on your answer:  I tried exactly the scenario that Thomas suggested.  I couldn't **build** lib2, because it didn't have the reference.  When I changed the function to look like what I have in my answer, then I could build it. Yes, Visual Studio will copy all associated dlls over.  But you still need to *specifically* include a reference to any assembly which you need in order to parse the signatures.  That's not auto-inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ILMerge would solve this problem. The idea is you create 2 dlls and merge them into one. That way you can have a single dll but reference it twice. Then way you can separate the GUI code from other code and only add the reference that you need to the particular project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. It is because the method is decalre as public. This mean that it is visible to `lib2.dll` (in your case.) In other word you can call this method.

It also has a constrain that only classes inherited from `DependencyObject` can call this method. So that is the reason why you need to reference 'WindowsBase'.