# dependencies with generic static methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In project on which I've been working from last months I met odd problem. In solution I have three projects **project C**, **project B** which refers to C and **project A** which refers to B. In project B I wrote a helper static class which contains couple of generic static methods. It looks something like that:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void DoStuff(T param) where T : ClassFromAssemblyC // It's ofcs some   typical class which is defined in assemblyC

    public static int SomeOrdinaryNonGenericMethod()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then when I've tried to build solution I got an error in project A with message "Error  3   The type 'ClassFromAssemblyC' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'projectC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

I was able to reproduce this problem in test project with one change, I have to use in project A one of 
non generic method of class which contains the generic method (referring to example I used SomeOrdinaryNonGenericMethod(). When I'm changing definition of method DoStuff to look like 
public static void DoStuff(ClassFromAssemblyC param) 
everything is building properly. Also when i am changing access modifier fom public to private everything works fine. Generally I have two questions:

1. Why generic static methods broke build even if they are not used
2. Is there possible another situation when a generic method forced Project A to refer Project C even if any member nor method of class which contain that method is not used.

***Update:***

I've found a description of the similar problem to mine:

[Mixing generic methods and extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492600/mixing-generic-methods-and-extension-methods)

To sum up i think the good answer for sort of this problems is quote from this topic: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/668498/problem-with-extension-method-in-c-compiler

> Generally, the C# compiler makes no promises that referencing a library will require less than the transitive closure of that library's own references. In practice, the compiler will attempt to load only the metadata it needs for binding, and you usually get away with a much smaller subset, but there are no guarantees. The solution in those cases is to add the missing reference indicated.

Comment: if *your code*, in some way, shape or form, might need to understand the types from `AssemblyC`, then you need a reference. This could be because of possible overloads (even if it's not the overload you want to use) or any more general type resolution (such as generic constraints)

Comment: Thanks for an answer but i'm still wondering why compile error occurs only when I use one of the Foo class methods.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter if you are using the method or not. If a public method is somehow *using* the unreferenced type. There are (as far as I know) two scenarios where this can happen:

1. A method is returning a type which is located in an unreferenced library
2. A method is accepting a type which is located in an unreferenced library